# Fallo en Debian

Tags: linux, debian

GNU/Linux Debian 7 (Wheezy) está arrojando el siguiente error:

```
Reason: 2017-01-11 06:25:38 INFO: pum is called with arguments: ['--list', '--repo-info', '--json']
2017-01-11 06:25:42 ERROR: W:Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ulises.hostalia.com:http:
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
2017-01-11 06:25:42 ERROR: Exited with returncode 1.
```

¿Qué puede ser y cómo lo puedo evitar?

Comment: Hola @Killpe, ¿se solucionó el problema? ¿leíste mi última nota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servidor web de `http://http.debian.net/debian/...` redirige las peticiones a un cierto número de servidores (como `debian.redparra.com`, `debian.redimadrid.es`, `ulises.hostalia.com`, etc), entre los que se encuentra el que te ha dado error.

Parece que estaba parado en el momento de ejecutar tu comando, cuando escribo estas palabras está funcionando correctamente.

Si repites de nuevo el comando que te lanzó ese mensaje debería funcionar correctamente ahora.

Comment: Probaré otra vez, pero me da el error casi todos los días 

Comment: ¿Sólo te falla ese servidor o en más? Es decir, cuando te falla lo hace en ese servidor en particular o en otros más?

Comment: solo ese, el resto van bien

Comment: ¿Puedes acceder a [esta URL](http://ulises.hostalia.com/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/) y navegar por sus directorios sin problemas? Si puedes acceder desde un navegador quizá deberíamos centrarnos en alguna configuración (archivo `hosts`, `resolv.conf`, `apt-conf`, etc) que esté interfiriendo con el funcionamiento normal del programa.

Comment: Por cierto, en particular el archivo que trata de descargar es [ESTE](http://ulises.hostalia.com/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2). Si quieres ver qué archivos trata de descargar puedes usar `apt-get update --print-uris`.

Comment: Hola @oscargarcia. Desde mi ordenador lo veo sin problemas, desde el servidor no se como navegar por el ya que no tiene entorno gráfico :(

Comment: Acabo de probar con un ping y va perfecto, he hecho apt-get update y no da fallo ahora, se ve que hay momentos en los que tiene sobrecarga y falla en momentos puntuales. mil gracias @oscargarcia y a todos por la ayuda :)

Comment: Me alegra que ya te funcione. Cuando falle siempre puedes usar `curl "http://ulises.hostalia.com/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/"` o bien `wget -O - "http://ulises.hostalia.com/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/" para depurar qué ocurre (un mensaje de error más detallado) aunque no tengas navegador gráfico. O bien puedes probar a usar un navegador de línea de comandos como `lynx "http://ulises.hostalia.com/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/"`.

Comment: Genial @oscargarcia lo tendré a mano para cuando me vuelva a fallar a ver si descubro porque lo hace que cada 2x3 me lleva un mail del servidor con el fallo.

Answer (score 2):

```
2017-01-11 06:25:42 ERROR: W:Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ulises.hostalia.com:http:, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Justo ahí te está diciendo que tienes un fallo de conexión. ¿Es posible que no tengas acceso a internet?

De todos modos, creo que es mejor que preguntes en [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) que, me imagino, estarán más puestos en este tipo de cosas.

**EDICION:**
Si tu maquina tiene acceso a Internet, entonces es que la URL a la que intentas acceder no está disponible por alguna razón  (servidor caído, firewall, configuración de algún hipotético proxy...).

Comment: Tiene acceso a internet, de hecho es un servidor web.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta